# Google Analytics: No Pageview Request in Network Tab despite seeing Pageviews in Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

If I execute the following Code on my Site, I can see a Img Request in my Google Chrome DevTool Network Tab with the respecting Property ID "UA-99999999-9".

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-99999999-9', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Now let's get to the Problem:

If I'm executing the exact same code but with another Google Analytics Property ID, I can not see such a request in my Network Tab.

The strange thing is: The pageview shows up in Google Analytics.

So my question is: How can I see Pageviews in Google Analytics despite seeing no request going out in my Browser? And why can't I see a request in my Browser at all if I'm just exchanging the Property ID?

There are no such things as IP-Adress-Filters in use.
I've tested this with Google Chrome and Firefox, both with the stated result above.

Would appreciate if someone could explain me why I'm seeing no request.
Thanks to any of you in advance!